# Error while debugging a Classic asp application with vs 2012.The debugger was unable to resolve the specified computer name

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp-classic

I have an old classic ASP application which I want to debug in Visual Studio 2012 in order to fix some issues. I am running it on Windows 10 with IIS Version 10 (at least that's what I can see in the about window).

To enable debugging in the *Properties Window -> Start Option* (in VS 2012) I have made it `Use Custom Server. Base Url: http://localhost`.

Here is the screenshot:
[VS 2012 Set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jBjA.png)

At IIS level, I have made sure I have ASP enabled as well as the server/client script debugging.

[Windows Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YTKM.png)

But still when I am trying to run the application with "F5" I am getting the below error:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The debugger cannot
>   connect to the remote computer. The debugger was unable to resolve the
>   specified computer name.

I have been struggling for days on this. Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you literally have it as `Base Url: http://localhot`? Not `localhost`? (The screenshot is so tiny as to be unusable.)

Comment: Thanks Martha, you are right. There was this typo, so silly of me. But on correcting this error also I am getting this following message:                            ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly. See help for common configuration errors. Running the web page outside of the debugger may provide further information.

Click Help for more information.
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------